# System 30/40% high cpu at the start

Tags: windows, boot, drivers, cpu-usage, windows-10-pro

I'm really desperate.
I have a new laptop but when I start it or restarts the "system" process eats up 30-40% of the cpu for a couple of minutes. I did a check and this is what I found inside of this process:
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmW9d.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Run MSCONFIG (Winkey+R) and start with minimal services.  Add services until you see what the issue is. Have you contact the Manufacturer's Support people?

Comment: @John i did another fresh install and the issue continues to exist. I think I need to talk to support.

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: I have a I7-1065g7

Comment: I reinstalled the bios driver and the problem seem to have stopped. I'll delete this post in 2 days if completely stops.